# ipad is showing my site at full height and not 980 full width

Tags: ipad, height, width

I have created a [site](http://www.econiq.com) and it works fine on all the major browsers unfortunately when viewed on a mobile device it is viewed at full height so the width of the site changes per page and I have an annoying white space to the right of the screen.
I have tried `meta name="viewport" content="width=988"  or (width=988)` this does not seem to make any difference or  `meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"` (or variations of it).

this really messed things up as it cut off the right third of the background images. Both leave the white space to the right. I have also tried :

```
@media only screen and (device-width:768px)and (orientation:portrait)
/*iPad Portrait orientation styles */

@media only screen and (device-width:768px)and (orientation:landscape)
/*iPad landscape orientation styles */
```

in the css but this hasn't done anything, in fairness I don't really understand how that's supposed to work. I think the main problem is the ipad wants to scale the page to full height and I want it full width.
Any ideas?

Comment: are you talking about making website responsive ?